# SFML - Rendering a character when the key is pressed?

Tags: c++, rendering, character, sfml, tdm-mingw

So I've got this program that is supposed to imitate a console (with a little coding help from [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1119972/teh-internets-is-made-of-catz)):

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

sf::Color fontColor;
sf::Font mainFont;
sf::Clock myClock;

bool showCursor = true;

void LoadFont() {
    mainFont.loadFromFile("dos.ttf");
    fontColor.r = 0;
    fontColor.g = 203;
    fontColor.b = 0;
}

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow wnd(sf::VideoMode(1366, 768), "SFML Console");
    wnd.setSize(sf::Vector2u(1366, 768));

    LoadFont();

    sf::Text myTxt;
    myTxt.setColor(fontColor);
    myTxt.setString("System Module:");
    myTxt.setFont(mainFont);
    myTxt.setCharacterSize(18);
    myTxt.setStyle(sf::Text::Regular);
    myTxt.setPosition(0, 0);

    while(wnd.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event myEvent;

        while (wnd.pollEvent(myEvent)) {
            if (myEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                wnd.close();
            }

            if (myEvent.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
                if (myEvent.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) {
                    wnd.close();
                }
            }
        }

            wnd.clear();

            if (myClock.getElapsedTime() >= sf::milliseconds(500)) {
                myClock.restart();
                showCursor = !showCursor;

                if(showCursor == true) {
                    myTxt.setString("System Module:_");
                } else {
                    myTxt.setString("System Module:");
                }
            }

            wnd.draw(myTxt);
            wnd.display();
    }
}
```

I need to be able to let the user type a key on the keyboard, and then render that key on the screen. I'm thinking about using an `std::vector` of `sf::Keyboard::Key`, and use a while loop to check what the key is (looping through the `std::vector<sf::Keyboard::Key>`) without using a whole bunch of `if` statements, but I don't exactly know how to handle that yet, so I'd like to know if there is an easier way to accomplish my main goal. Suggestions? Comments?

Thank you for your time,
~Mike

Answer (score 2):

SFML has a nice feature for this, `sf::Event::TextEntered` ([tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-events.php)). That is typically what you want and it avoids you to do crazy things to interpret the text entered by the user.
Stock your text entered by adding every character into a `sf::String` (rather than `std::string`, it may deal better with sfml's unicode types ~ not sure, but that would need a little check) which is then the perfect type for `sf::Text::setString` !

Don't hesitate to look at the [docs](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/annotated.php), it has further documentation in every classes' page.

Example:

```
sf::String userInput;
// ...
while( wnd.pollEvent(event))
{
    if(event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered)
    {
        /* Choose one of the 2 following, and note that the insert method
           may be more efficient, as it avoids creating a new string by
           concatenating and then copying into userInput.
        */
        // userInput += event.text.unicode;
        userInput.insert(userInput.getSize(), event.text.unicode);
    }
    else if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
    {
        if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::BackSpace) // delete the last character
        { 
            userInput.erase(userInput.getSize() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So would I append the typed `sf::Text` to the end of the buffer? If that's correct, how exactly am I supposed to get the end of the `sf::String` when the `sf::String::end` returns the beginning of the string? Look at this and see: http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1String.php

Comment: @Mike : Yes you have to append the text entered at the end of your buffer. You can use simply use the `+` operator to concatenate two `sf::String` (and therefore  use `+=`). About the documentation of `sf::String::end` it looks like a bad copy & paste from the author, I'm going to report it ! Obviously it should return an iterator to the end of the string, but iterators are meant to traverse the data, not to modify it. Instead use `sf::String::insert` and `sf::String::erase`.